# Implementing Hit Testing for Strokes of InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I've implemented a custom InkCanvas and multiple custom Strokes, which are described here:
[Custom Rendering Ink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Every thing works fine, except I can't do Hit Testing on my strokes.
At the "Implementing Custom Strokes" section of the above link, it says:

> The Stroke class can also perform hit testing. You can also implement your own hit testing algorithm by overriding the HitTest method in the current class.

but i cant find any override-able version of HitTest method there!!!

Can anybody please help me implement hit testing on a custom stroke?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, found the solution.

```
    protected override void OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EditingMode == InkCanvasEditingMode.Select)
        {
            var strokes = Strokes.Where(x => (x is CustomStroke) && ((CustomStroke)x).HitTestPoint(e.GetPosition(this))).ToList();

            if (strokes.Any())
                Select(new StrokeCollection(strokes));
        }
        base.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
    }
```